# How are emotional distress damages quantified?

Tags: california, damages, settlement

In TV lawsuits, it's common for the plaintiff to request large amounts of money for emotional distress not caused by physical harm.

What actual guidelines can be used in California for evaluating the amount of damages a plaintiff should aim to recover in a settlement regarding intentionally inflicted emotional distress? What are some examples a layperson can look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is a 1999 report on the topic](http://www.theemploymentlawyers.com/Articles/Emotional%20distress%20damages.htm). It has actual figures and a brief description of dozens of types of emotional damage award amounts. Along with complete case citations for further research.

There are about 30 different categories and the amounts range from about $25,000 to $300,000.

It's not a comprehensive answer to the question. But at least it can give you a feel for the types and amounts in play.

Comment: "Confusion ($25,000), ($60,000) (feeling intimidated), ($50,000) headaches,  ($40,000) (self-doubt)" - amazing! Thank you.